# Selecting a certain item from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php

I have an multi-dimensional array called shifts which contains the day (e.g. Monday) and then the shift (e.g. 12:00 - 16:00)

I'm looking to do something like:

```
$monday = shift from array where day equals Monday
```

My array currently looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [day] => Saturday [shift] => Day Off! ) 
        [1] => Array ( [day] => Sunday [shift] => Day Off! ) 
        [2] => Array ( [day] => Monday [shift] => 11:00-19:00 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [day] => Tuesday [shift] => 08:00-17:00 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [day] => Wednesday [shift] => 08:00-17:00 ) 
        [5] => Array ( [day] => Thursday [shift] => 16:00-01:00 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [day] => Friday [shift] => 16:00-01:00 ) )
```

Array is built using this code:

```
$shifts = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT day, shift FROM ps_shifts WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND week_begin = '$week_1_begin'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $shifts[] = $day;
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Why not use a map?
You could try $shifts = array("Monday"=> 16:00-01:100,"Tuesday"=>11:00-21:00..)
and then simply call each shift using $shits[day]
Provided you have the option of changing the data structuring ofcourse.

Comment: I'm selecting the day and shift from MYSQL and then using a while loop to create the array, would it be possible to change this to use maps? Check updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* to refine on what was said above lets take the the data as such:*/

```
$data = array(
      array ( 'day' => 'Saturday', 'shift' => 'Day Off!' ),
      array ( 'day' => 'Sunday', 'shift' => 'Day Off!' ),
      array ( 'day' => 'Monday', 'shift' => '11:00-19:00' ),
      /* ... */
      );
```

/* we then take that data and transform it, that is flatten it to day=>shift. call it shifts*/

```
$shifts = array();

$days = array('Saturday','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday', 'Friday');

foreach ($data as $i=>$s) {
      $shifts[$days[$i]] = $data[$i]['shift'];
```

}

/* this returns an array like:

```
$shifts = array (
'Saturday' => 'Day Off!',
'Sunday' => 'Day Off!',
'Monday' => '11:00-19:00',
    );
```

*/

/* then to get the shift for any day is as simple as.*/

```
$monday_shift =  $shifts['Monday'];

print "monday shift is:  $monday_shift\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the day as the array key.

So:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $shifts[$day['day']] = $day;
}
```

Then you could get it by doing this:

```
$shift_time = $shifts['Monday']['shift'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved based on 'jd182' anwser, however the provided code didn't work so I modified to this:

```
$shifts = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT day, shift FROM ps_shifts WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND week_begin = '$week_1_begin'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $shifts[$row['day']] = $row['shift'];
}

echo $shifts['Monday'];
```